# Mongodb aggregate push index

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```
  {
    _id: "1",
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "Doe",
    cars: [
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "carName": "BMW",
        "carModel": "330",
        "carColor": "silver"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "carName": "BMW",
        "carModel": "330",
        "carColor": "pink"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5",
        "carName": "Lexus",
        "carModel": "IS300",
        "carColor": "white"
      },
      {
        "_id": "6",
        "carName": "LADA",
        "carModel": "2106",
        "carColor": "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Using an aggregate query I'm returning particular objects from the `cars` array of the following document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      firstName: "john"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$cars"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "cars.carName": {
        "$in": [
          "Lexus",
          "LADA"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      cars: {
        $push: "$cars"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Is it possible to also get the index of each object pushed to the `cars` array?

For example:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "cars": [
      {
        "_id": "5",
        "carColor": "white",
        "carModel": "IS300",
        "carName": "Lexus",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "6",
        "carColor": "blue",
        "carModel": "2106",
        "carName": "LADA",
        "index": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The aggregation query can be tested [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J5AfyXvrLO9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation ([**`includeArrayIndex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/))

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "firstName": "john" }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$cars", "includeArrayIndex": "index", }},
  { "$match": { "cars.carName": { "$in": ["Lexus", "LADA"] }}},
  { "$addFields": { "cars.index": "$index" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "cars": { "$push": "$cars" }
  }}
])
```

[**Mongoplayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VWJtjIsDTBy)

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this without using `$mergeObjects`? I have mongoDb with the version of 3.2 and it does not support that property.

Comment: I* have udpated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer helped me a lot! I got stuck in this index issue for hours.